# Laraver query Union All

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have query like these

```
SELECT id,image1 image FROM product_catalog
WHERE id='1' AND image1<>''
UNION ALL 
SELECT id,image2 image FROM product_catalog
WHERE id='1' AND image2<>''
UNION ALL 
SELECT id,image3 image FROM product_catalog
WHERE id='1' AND image3<>''
UNION ALL 
SELECT id,image4 image FROM product_catalog
WHERE id='1' AND image4<>''
```

But my problem is i cant convert to laraevl query building, so any idea how to convert my query??
I just try these :

```
$img1 = Product_catalog::select('id','image2 as image')->from('product_catalog')->where('id', '=', $id)->where('image2', '<>', '');
$img2 = Product_catalog::select('id','image3 as image')->from('product_catalog')->where('id', '=', $id)->where('image3', '<>', '')->unionAll($img1);
$img3 = Product_catalog::select('id','image4 as image')->from('product_catalog')->where('id', '=', $id)->where('image4', '<>', '')->unionAll($img2);                    
$imgall = Product_catalog::select('id','image1 as image')->from('product_catalog')->where('id', '=', $id)->where('image1', '<>', '')->unionAll($img3)->get();
```

But is not working. Any idea?
NOTE : I'm using mysql for query building

Comment: Move all `->unionAll` to the last statement.

Comment: and how to get all union like img1, img2, img3, and img4??

Comment: Obviously `$imgall = Product_catalog::select('id','image1 as image')->from('product_catalog')->where('id', '=', $id)->where('image1', '<>', '')->unionAll($img1)->unionAll($img2)->unionAll($img3)->get();`